# Synchronise UILocalNotification to the Watch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification, apple-watch

On my iPhone Application, I create UILocalNotification. I would like to know how to synchronize the UILocalNotification on the Apple Watch. That means to make the notification appear on the Watch when it appears on the iPhone.

It's my UILocalNotification (this notification appear in 91 secondes and I would like to appear in phone and watch):

```
        UILocalNotification *verif_exterieur_notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    verif_exterieur_notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:91];
    verif_exterieur_notification.alertTitle = @"Vérifications extérieures:";
    verif_exterieur_notification.alertBody = @"Assurez vous d'avoir bien vérifié(e) l'éxterieur de votre avion avant de vous installer !";
    verif_exterieur_notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    verif_exterieur_notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication ]scheduleLocalNotification:verif_exterieur_notification];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to achieve this. The system automatically decides on which device it will show the notification.
If your iPhone is locked and your Watch is on your wrist, you should automatically receive the notification on your Watch. Also make sure that the notifications are turned on for your app in the Watch app on your iPhone and that your Watch is not in Do Not Disturb mode.

Comment: ok so how to create a static notification interface when the UIlocalNOtification appear on the Iphone ? Thanks

Comment: You have to add a notification extension target to your app. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251)

Comment: notification extension ? for the Watch ? I don't understand the tutorial

Comment: You asked for the phone... For the watch you just add a Notification Interface Controller in Interface Builder and that's it.

Comment: ok, perfect, and how to create notification center in interface builder ?

Comment: The notification centre obviously needs to be created and handled programatically.